# Can I mirror a Bezier curve and not turn it into mesh

Tags: bezier-curves

If I try to apply the mirror modifier to a curve, it tells me I need to convert it to a mesh. I also tried to mirror via "Object > Mirror", which simply sets the scale to -1. If I apply the scale, the curve tilt is all messed up.

Is there a way to mirror a curve without those problems?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, mirror it in edit mode.

In object mode:

- Set 3D cursor to object (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)

In edit mode:

- then in edit mode select all (if not selected) (<kbd>A</kbd>)
- set transform align to 3D-cursor(<kbd>.</kbd>)
- duplicate (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>Esc</kbd>)
- mirror (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>
  or <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't mirror the tilt of the curve vertices. Is there an option to mirror the tilt aswell?

Answer (score 2):

In 2.98 and later you *can* add a [Mirror modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html) to a Bezier curve and use a [Hook modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/hooks.html) and an empty if you want the mirror point to be one of the end points of the Curve.

- Create your Bezier curve.
- Move the 3D cursor to the end of the curve you want to be the mirror point.
- Add an empty. It will appear at the mirror point.
- Edit the Bezier curve and select the end point.
- Add a hook modifier, set it to the empty, and assign it.
- Add a Mirror modifier, assign the Mirror Object field to the empty, and adjust axis as you'd like.

Here's a simple Bezier curve, mirrored on its left end:

[image: Bezier curve and empty showing mirroring]

Here's the modifier stack

[image: Modifier stack described above]

You have to remember that when you want to move that endpoint you do it by moving the empty.  Otherwise you can treat the original exactly as you would otherwise.